# Possible to target element by nth-child "globally"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Suppose I have a hierararchy like:

```
ul
    li
    li

ul 
    li
    li      <----- 
    li
```

Can I target the marked `li` by `li:nth-child(4)` or something similar?

Comment: I believe [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) gives you this functionality. But I'm not 100%.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery.

User `jQuery.eq();`

Try this simple Example ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5qe2C/)).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("li:eq(6)").css("color", "red");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
        </ul>

        <ul>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
            <li>7</li>
            <li>8</li>
        </ul>   
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can do this:

```
ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2){
    color:#F00;
}
```

Which I think would be the closest to what you looking for.

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HUtec/)

Answer (score 0):

With pure css, I don't think that its possible to select `li` globally. You have to select the `ul` element first.

```
ul:last-child li:nth-child(2)
```

(Here I am targeting the second element of last `ul`).

The main thing you just need to use first selector for `ul` then selector for `li`

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bELA5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
li:nth-last-of-type(2)
```

source: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

The is no global order. You could use this:

```
ul:nth-of-type(2) li:nth-child(2){
    color:#F00;
}
```